# Is it safe to perform read and "set" operation on List by different threads without locking mechanism

Tags: java, multithreading

It is pretty unsafe to iterate over a `List`, which is being performed **add / remove** operation by another thread.

That's why we need need `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                // java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
                for (String s : list) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }
        }

    });
    thread.start();

    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        list.add("string" + i);    
    }

    Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

However, how about **set** operation. Currently, the following code doesn't throw any exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("dummy");

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                for (String s : list) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }
        }

    });
    thread.start();

    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        list.set(0, "smart");
    }

    Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Even though there isn't any unexpected outcome, I was wondering, if the thread only performing **set** operation on the `List`, is it a good practice that we don't using any locking mechanism, or copy n write mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the javadoc of [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely **setting the value of an element is not a structural modification**.)

So no, it does not need to be synchronized.